# Why is git merge saying two branches are up-to-date?

Tags: git, merge

We have an MVC5 web application and I am confused why git is telling me 2 branches are up-to-date.

The two branches are `master` and `feature1`. When I am on `feature1` and do `git merge master` I get

> `Already up-to-date.`

This doesn't make sense as the branches are not the same.

We have checked with Beyond Compare and there are several files which are different - taking one as an example `feature1` has a file where a line is commented out, in `master` the same line is **not** commented out.

I have checked that my local repo has the same as the remote (it is).

Why is git telling me these branches are the same, when they have differences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing a merge doesn't mean that the branches will become same. It's just that the new changes of the different branch will be merged onto the existing branch.

If you have a line commented out in the feature1 branch and that was of course done after it was taken out from the master, then merging from master will not remove that comment.

Answer (score 2):

`git merge` doesn't mean that your branches will be the same.

In your case if `feature1` originated from `master` and if you have made some changes to the code in feature1 branch then these branches will be different, but `git merge` will show you that everything is up to date, because all the code from `master` is already in `feature1` branch and there is nothing to update.

It would have been different story if you tried to merge `feature1` into `master`.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want both branches to be the same, as opposed to up to date. To do this, you need to merge both branches into each other.

In other words:

- Merging BranchA into BranchB does not guarantee the same content in the HEAD of both branches.
- Merging BranchA into BranchB and BranchB into BranchA guarantees the same content in the HEAD of both branches