# Git says branches are both the same and different

Tags: git, gitlab

I don't have much experience with git, so forgive me if this is obvious. I had an issue when merging 2 branches. I have 3 branches: development, uat and master. In CLI, if I type "git diff development..uat", it is blank. If I do the same thing with either dev/uat to master, there are pages of diffs displayed. However, when I put "git merge --no-ff uat", it says this branch is up-to-date. Ultimately, I want  Master to be exactly the same as the code in both dev and uat. When I merged in gitlab, it merged only the last commit. I can physically go through the code in gitlab and see the differences, yet it tells me when I try to merge there that all branches are identical. Am I missing an obvious solution? Is there some way to force Master to accept the changes?

I looked at [Why is git merge saying two branches are up-to-date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39467880/why-is-git-merge-saying-two-branches-are-up-to-date) but the situation didn't seem to be the same, nor did they actually tell the asker what the solution was.

Comment: Can you make sure you have master checked-out before you merge?

Comment: I absolutely did.

Comment: Screenshots or copy/paste output would be helpful.  `git branch -a`'s output would be helpful.  At one point you say `master`, at another you say `Master`.  These are case _sensitive_.  Is it possible you have a `Master` and a `master`?

Comment: Sorry, any inadvertant capitalization was in the comment above, not in git.   
`git branch -a  
  development  
* master  
  uat  
  remotes/origin/development  
  remotes/origin/master  
  remotes/origin/patch-1  
  remotes/origin/revert-0e747ee0  
  remotes/origin/revert-366fbd48  
  remotes/origin/revert-3e2e3cd4  
  remotes/origin/uat`

Comment: Sorry, apparently I don't have Stackoverflow comment formatting down either :)

Comment: Couple of questions for clarification:
1) You don't have differences between uat and develop?
2) You have differences between uat/develop and master?
3) You want to get uat/develop's changes into master?

Comment: Yes to all 3 of those Mauricio

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

> Ultimately, I want Master to be exactly the same as the code in both dev and uat.

Here you will have to decide what you want your *graph* to look like.  You can make a new commit with the *tree* taken from the commit identified by either `development` or `uat`.  Those may be one single commit, named twice, or two separate commits with two different names but the same content.

You'll need to look at the commit graph you have now and decide what you *want* the graph to look like, knowing how `git merge` uses the graph so that *future* `git merge`s do the right thing.  This means that you need to know a lot more about how Git works.

## Long

I think you need to rewind at least a little bit: you're making assumptions about how you think Git does (or should?) work, that aren't the case.  (Well, that might be vacuously true: if you did something in Git and it worked exactly as you expected, why would you post to StackOverflow? :-) )

#### Commits

First, let's talk about what Git's commits *are*, in a very concrete sense, with examples.  Here's an actual Git commit object in the Git repository for Git:

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD
0afbf6caa5b16dcfa3074982e5b48e27d452dbbb
$ git cat-file -p 0afbf6caa5b16dcfa3074982e5b48e27d452dbbb | sed 's/@/ /'
tree 443f5d668dba30e35fd1d338fb533d3cedfe60b0
parent e215e89791b97ebb6831504480c8ab4734a2117e
author Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1521151265 -0700
committer Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1521151265 -0700

Git 2.17-rc0

Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
```

That's the whole commit, but much less than the whole story:

- The `tree` line above represents a *complete snapshot* of the source code for Git, as of this particular commit.
- The `parent` line gives the hash ID of the commit that came just before this commit.
- The `author` and `committer` lines identify who made the commit—name and email address—and the time-stamp.
- The rest of the file, after the first blank line, contains the log message.  Git doesn't care how this is formatted, but this log message is formatted as if it were an email message: subject-line, blank-line, body (in this case the body is just the signed-off-by line).

All of these are important, and it's the assemblage of stuff here—the byte sequence, including those two time stamps that represent 15 March 2018 at just after 3 PM PDT, that Git uses to compute the actual hash ID, in this case that big ugly `0afbf6c...` number.  No two different commits will ever have the same hash ID, so if you have the hash ID, you have the commit, and if you don't have the hash ID, you don't have the commit.

This means that the hash ID *is*, in a sense, the "true name" of the commit.  Git passes around the hash IDs as shorthand for "the entire block of text above".  If it needs more, it looks up the text and gets what it needs out of that.  If all it needs to know is *which commit is this?*, it uses the hash ID.

Note that most commits have exactly one `parent` line.  Some—*merge* commits—have two, and at least one commit, the very first one ever made in a repository, has none.  These let Git find *earlier* commits from later ones.  This connection goes only one way: from later commit, to earlier commit.  That's because each commit, once written, can *never be changed*.<sup>1</sup>  This result is that child commits know their parents, which exist when the child is made; but parent commits are unaware of their children.

All of this means that we can *string together* a series of commits:

```
A  <-B  <-C
```

Here `A` is the very first commit and has no `parent` line.  Git calls this a *root* commit.  `B` is the second commit, so its `parent` line lists commit `A`'s hash ID.  C is the third commit so its `parent` lists `B`.  We say that `C` *points to* `B`, and `B` points to `A`.

We need a way to find the hash ID of `C`.  Once we *have* that, we can read `C` and find its `parent` to get the hash ID of `B`, and so on, but where do we get the actual hash ID for `C`?  The answer in Git is: *use a branch name*.  The *name*, such as `master`, stores the actual hash ID, so that it *points to* commit `C`:

```
A <-B <-C   <--master
```

Git therefore works *backwards:* branch names point to the *last* commit, and Git works back from there to earlier commits.

---

<sup>1</sup>Remember that we said the hash ID is a result of doing some hairy computation on the commit's data, the stuff we saw with `git cat-file -p`.  If you were to *change* any of that, the hash we'd get doing the same computation on the *new* data would be different.  We'd no longer have *this* commit; we'd have some *other* commit instead!

---

#### How branches grow

We know commits are read-only and that the arrows always point backwards, so we stop drawing them that carefully (because it's too hard in text on StackOverflow) and draw this as:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
```

and now we're ready to see how branches grow.  First, let's use `git checkout -b dev` or `git branch dev` to make a *new* branch name that *also* points to commit `C`:

```
A--B--C   <-- master, dev
```

Now that we have two, we need a way to know which branch we're talking about.  Let's attach the word `HEAD` to one of these two, specifically to `dev`:

```
A--B--C   <-- master, dev (HEAD)
```

Now let's make a *new* commit, in the usual way (modify files, `git add`, `git commit`).  When Git is done packaging up the commit—making the snapshot, putting in the `parent` line, putting in our name and the date as the author and committer, and putting in our log message—Git will compute a new hash ID for the new commit object that Git stores in the object database.  Let's use the letter `D` to stand in for this new commit.  Since `D`'s parent is the current commit `C`, let's draw it in:

```
A--B--C
       \
        D
```

What Git does now is to write `D`'s actual hash ID to whichever *name* our `HEAD` is attached-to:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
       \
        D   <-- dev (HEAD)
```

#### Names mean commits, but also mean more

The name `master` here *means* "commit `C`", and the name `dev` or `HEAD` means "commit `D`".  However, sometimes we want to talk about a whole collection of commits, such as "commits `C` back to `A` inclusive".  The name `master` identifies `C`, and `C` leads to `B` which leads to `A`, so:

```
$ git log master
```

will show us all three commits.  So the name `master` also—sometimes!—means "commit `C` and everything earlier".

By the same token, `dev` *also* means "`D` and everything earlier".  *That includes `C`, `B`, and `A` again.*  In Git, *commits can be on multiple branches*.  (This isn't true in many other version control systems!)  So Git gives us this funny `..` syntax:

```
master..dev
```

which means "all commits in `dev`, except for all commits in `master`".  When as `dev` immediately follows `master` like this, it seems pretty clear.  Don't worry, it will get confusing again! :-)

#### Comparing commits

Note that the snapshot for commit `D` is independent of the snapshots for any of the previous commits, but if we *compare* the snapshot in `D` with the snapshot in its parent `C`, we see what *changed* between the two commits.  That's whatever we just did to make `D`.

We'll get this same thing shown to us however we go about comparing `C` vs `D`:

```
$ git diff <hash-of-C> <hash-of-D>
```

or:

```
$ git diff master dev
```

or:

```
$ git diff master..dev
```

or for that matter:

```
$ git show dev
```

because `git show` does the same thing as `git log` for printing the log message of the one commit, followed by a diff of the parent vs the child.

Now, there's something else funny about `master..dev` here, when using `git diff`, but to get to it we need to go a bit further.  Let's add another commit on `dev`.  To do that, let's make the *reverse* of the change we just made: if we added a line to `README.md`, let's take that same line back out.  If we changed some other file, let's change it *back*.  Then we'll make a new commit `E`:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
       \
        D--E   <-- dev (HEAD)
```

Note that our name `dev` now points to commit `E`.  The *saved snapshot* for `E` matches that for `C`, so if we run:

```
$ git diff master dev
```

we see *nothing!*

If we run:

```
$ git log master..dev
```

we will see commit `E`, then commit `D`, showing us that there are two commits contained in—i.e., *reachable from*—`dev` (`E`) that are not in `master`.  We start at `E` and walk back to `D`, then walk back to `C`, but now we've hit commits that are reachable from commit `C` (a commit is always reachable from itself: we walk zero steps).

You might expect:

```
$ git diff master..dev
```

to show something, but it doesn't: for `git log`, and in fact for *most* Git commands, `master..dev` means *do the usual walking with exclusion* that we just saw.  But `git diff` just totally ignores the `..` and pretends we put in a space instead: it finds the commit to which `master` points, and the commit to which `dev` points, and compares *those* commits, completely ignoring commit `D`.

#### Your situation

Your graph is going to be more tangled.  Use a Git command that will show it to you, then try re-drawing it yourself horizontally on a whiteboard or some such.  (This is a good exercise in learning Git commit graphs.)  You can have a GUI show you the graph, if you have one, or you can use:

```
$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
```

which you can remember as `Git Log with A DOG`.

Your graph will have many commits and possibly multiple points of forking-and-joining:

```
...--o--...--o--...----------o--...---M   <-- master
      \       \             /
       o--...--o--...--N   /   <-- development
                \         /
                 o--...--O   <-- uat
```

is probably far simpler than your actual graph (and of course the actual hash IDs are big ugly strings, not simple single letters like `M` and `N`).

Your `git diff development uat` tells us that whatever commit `development` names—this may or may not be the *same* commit as `uat`; I've drawn them as different commits here—their *snapshots* are the same.

The commit to which your `master` points is very different, so you see lots of output.

When you run `git merge`, though—well, *this* is the point where all this graph-drawing pays off.

#### What `git merge` is about

From a high level perspective, `git merge` is all about *combining work*.  To combine work, Git needs a *common starting point*.  With a really simple graph:

```
A--B--C---F   <-- master (HEAD)
       \
        D--E   <-- dev
```

it's easy to see where the common starting point is: here, it's commit `C`.

Git will find the common starting point for you, based on your actual commit graph.  This particular commit is called the *merge base*.  Then *merging* consists, in essence, of making two diffs:

- Compare the merge base to the HEAD commit.  This is what *we* did.
- Compare the merge base to the other commit, such as the tip of `dev`.  This is what *they* did.
- Whatever we both did to the base, combine those changes.
- Finally, if all goes well, make a *new* commit on the current branch, but this time with *two* parents.  The first parent is the same as usual: the `HEAD` at the time of the merge.  The second parent is the other commit.  This new commit advances the current branch, to which `HEAD` is attached, as usual:

  ```
  A--B--C---F--G   <-- master (HEAD)
         \    /
          D--E   <-- dev
  ```

  and the merge is now complete.

Suppose we do this merge, and then make another commit:

```
A--B--C---F--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
       \    /
        D--E   <-- dev
```

and ask Git to merge `dev` again.  What happens?  Well, Git still starts by finding the *merge base*.  It will look at our current commit `H` and backwards: `H`, `G`, then `F`-and-`E`-at-the-same-time, then `C`-and-`D`-at-the-same-time, and so on.  It will also look at `E`, and then `D`, and then `C`, and so on.

The *first* or *best* shared commit this time is not `C`, it's `E`!  `E` is very close to the tip of `dev`; in fact, it *is* the tip of `dev`.  `E` is close to the tip of `master` too: it's just two steps back, from `H` to `G` to `E`.  So the *merge base* is now commit `E`.

If we compare `E` to `E`, what *changes* will we have on their branch?  There are none here.  We can compare `E` to `H` to find out what we did, but combining that with *nothing*, the result will clearly be "what we did".  There's no point in doing another merge: `E` is already in our history.  So Git will say: `Already up-to-date.`

The fact that merges make these extra connections, so that the *reachable history* from the tip commit includes all the other branch's commits, is a key to using `git merge`.

#### Getting what you want, once you figure out what that is

Since your Git is saying `already up-to-date`, your graph must have `uat` as a commit directly reachable from your current `HEAD` commit.

That might be OK.  Draw the graph you have and consider the graph you *want* to have in the future.  Do you need to add new commits that tie graph sections together?  Or do you just want to make a new ordinary (non-merge) commit on `master`, using the *source code* from the `uat` or `development` commit?

To do the latter, you must overwrite the *index* aka *staging area*—this is where you have Git build up the next commit—with the tree from the `uat` or `development` commit.  One way that mostly works is:

```
$ git checkout uat -- .
```

which tells Git to extract every file from the commit to which `uat` points, into the index, and then into the work-tree.  The only thing this *doesn't* do is *remove* any files that are currently in the index and work-tree, but aren't in the commit to which `uat` points.

If there are no such files, you're ready to commit.  If there are some, you can remove them now, or you can first remove *everything*, then do the checkout:

```
$ git rm -r .               # remove *everything*
$ git checkout uat -- .     # refill from the uat commit
```

The initial "remove all" is OK for files that *do* exist in `uat`: you were going to overwrite using all the files that are in `uat`, so it does not matter if you first remove them, then replace them, vs just overwriting them.  The initial "remove all" is *necessary* for files that *don't* exist in `uat`: you could do it later, for just those files, but we've moved it to the other end of this operation.

#### A last note about `git reset`

There's one other way to make `master` match `uat` if `uat` is an ancestor of `master`, using `git reset`.  You will simply *discard* commits that are currently reachable from `master` that you don't want.

Let's start again with a graph drawing:

...--B--...---V--W--X--Y   <-- master (HEAD)
         \         /
          C--...--U   <-- uat

`W` is the merge result of merging `uat` into `master`; `X` and `Y` are commits after that; `V` is a commit before that that's *not* reachable from `uat`.  At some point in the past, `uat` branched off: that's `B`.  There are probably more commits before `V` that aren't reachable from `U`, but are reachable from `master` now.

Suppose we now tell Git: *throw the existing `master` pointer away; instead, make `master` point to `U` directly.*  We will get this:

...--B--...---V--W--X--Y   [abandoned]
         \         /
          C--...--U   <-- master (HEAD), uat

Commits `V-W-X-Y` are now lost, because there's no easy way to find them.  Commits before `V` may also be lost, but commits `B` and `C` through `U` won't, because there are now two ways to find them: through the name `master`, or through `uat`.

The problems with resetting commits away like this are:

- You throw out some amount of history.  The commits in a Git repository *are* the history; but they are only there as long as you have a *name* you can use to find them!

  Sometimes this is what you want, so that means `git reset` is probably the right answer.  Sometimes it isn't, in which case `git reset` is definitely the wrong answer.
- Some other clone may still have the history: *they* might have commits `V-W-X-Y`, with some name identifying commit `Y`.  If your Git talks to their Git, your Git will see those as new commits it should *add*.  Those commits will then come back!

  If you really want some commits to be gone, and use `git reset` to get rid of them this way, you must make sure that *every other clone you will ever talk with* has also gotten rid of those same commits, or at least, never gives them back to you.  If you cannot or do not want to do that, don't use `git reset` like this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you run a `git log --oneline -10` on both development and master, and see if the SHA of those commits are different, also, if they are, run `git merge-base master development` to check what's the last common commit between the two of them.

And at last, check if the differences `git diff` show aren't just mode changes and actual code changes.

Comment: There are actual changes. I know what they are because they cause my deploy to Production to fail. I was just hoping for simple git command to basically just force merge 1 branch with the other, not just the most recent commit, which is what seems like happened.